# What is maximum RAM supportable by Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

What is the maximum supportable RAM by Linux? Assume that hardware is/supports 64-bit. Among all Linux distros.

Does it go up to 16 exabytes, or is it limited like with Windows which I believe is 192 gigabytes?

Comment: Not sure, but note that mainstream 64-bit CPUs (AMD64) only support a 48-bit address space, meaning 256 TB. [X86-64](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) [Why do 64 bit systems only have a 48 bit address space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716946/why-do-64-bit-systems-have-only-a-48-bit-address-space)

Comment: Your data on Windows is out of date, they can go up to 4T depending on edition.

Comment: 8 upvotes already? I just turn around for a while and impossible things are happening.

Comment: @Mat 192GB was Windows 7. 256GB is Windows 8. 512GB the special ones. None of them goes over 1TB, surely not up to 4TB. http://didyouknow.org/maximum-ram-on-windows-7-and-windows-8/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2012

Comment: Yeah, you gotta point there. But I mean normal Windows' types. Not a server.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)

These are probably a good basis, looking at RHEL6's capabilities, they're covered here, titled: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 technology capabilities and limits](http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/articles-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-technology-capabilities-and-limits).

[image: ss #1]

> **NOTE: [5]** The architectural limits are based on the capabilities of the Red Hat Enterprise Linux kernel and the physical hardware. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 limit is based on 46-bit physical memory addressing. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 limit is based on 40-bit physical memory addressing. All system memory should be balanced across NUMA nodes in a NUMA-capable system.

#### Kernel docs

Also if you take a look at the kernel docs, [Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt):

```
Virtual memory map with 4 level page tables:

0000000000000000 - 00007fffffffffff (=47 bits) user space, different per mm
```

So 2<sup>47</sup> bytes = 128TiB

Comment: 128TB RAM, imagine that power on your machine. "Dayum!"

Comment: @RikTelner that much power on your machine would be absolutely useless. Adding RAM only helps until you reach the ceiling above which you simply never use the extra RAM. Nothing you are likely to run on a home computer will even come close to using 128TB of RAM.

Comment: @terdon - this is for servers. We would regularly have VM servers (Massive Dell 910 boxes running VMware) that would come stock with 128/256/512GB RAM.

Comment: Servers are another matter altogether, my point was that RAM is not a magic wand that speeds up your computer with no limit. It only makes  a difference if your processes actually use it and terabytes of RAM will not be used today except in very specific and unusual cases. Having a few teras of RAM on my laptop will not make it work any faster for my daily use having, say 16G or so. And anyway, 512G is a far cry from 128T!

Comment: @terdon - yeah I wasn't commenting on your comment to RikTelner about the speed, only why you'd need this much RAM 8-). What you said to him is spot on.

Comment: @terdon I do realize. It's not "magic staff that boosts performance" but imagine that if you theoretically had 4.2GHz great dodecacore 64-bit processor. You could run practically anything, few hundred times and then lag can kiss your backside. This is what I meant. You say I cannot get close to 128TB?! Is this challenge? Find me one, it will be dead within a day.

Comment: --- and, on the home computer. I wouldn't do anything practical with it. But I bet. That easy script MS-Batch below 1kB can make it fall.

Comment: @RikTelner: We will see machines with more than 48 bit in 2020 (latest). Those in-memory-dbs want a lot of memory.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Uhm, I don't understand what do you mean by this? What is in-memory-dbs, why do they want a lot of memory and how it's related to topic or in-comment discussion?

Comment: @RikTelner: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_memory_database, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_HANA - that's why you see new servers that can be fitted with TB of RAM.

Comment: @RikTelner I think what he is saying that it doesn't matter how hardware develops, the software will be always enough capable to make it too slow. Although it is only my interpretation, he probable understood quite differently.